# Why does setting true/false value does not work for React states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a dropdown menu for sorting options with react.js but I realized that changing boolean values on React states is not valid.

```
            <div className="Sort">
                Sort by
              <select 
                value={this.state.selectValue} 
                onChange={this.sorting} 
              >
               <option value="index">Pokedex Index</option>
                <option value="ascecnding">Ascending</option>
                <option value="descending">Descending</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

Here is my drop down, and it calls this function when an option is selected

```
sorting(e) {

    if(e.target.value == "index") {

        this.setState({
            indexSort : !this.state.indexSort,
            ascendSort: !this.state.ascendSort,
            descendSort: !this.state.descendSort
        });

    } else if(e.target.value =="ascecnding") {

        this.setState({
            indexSort : !this.state.indexSort,
            ascendSort: !this.state.ascendSort,
            descendSort: !this.state.descendSort
        });

    } else {
        this.setState({
            indexSort : !this.state.indexSort,
            ascendSort: !this.state.ascendSort,
            descendSort: !this.state.descendSort
        });
    }
}
```

Is looks very ugly because I cannot directly set like indexSort: false.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Aren't your three conditionals doing the exact same thing? Can't you remove those entirely, and just chuck the three sorts directly in `sorting(e) { }`?

Comment: Yeah I forgot to change. But my point of the question was how to do disable the other two when one is selected when I cannot use true/false. And by the way, the initial setting is "index" so this begins as True.

Comment: It is valid to set true/false in component state https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/mnt376a7/3/ ... maybe the reason your state is not being set to true/false is in another part of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having three different indicators and turning them on and off I think you should rather have one single source of truth and change only that value.

Your `<select>`'s value is derived from the state's `selectValue`, so that's the only value you need to change. The other three state properties (indexSort, ascendSort and descendSort) are unnecessary.

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/lxqm8wqj5z

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectValue: 'index'
    }
    this.sorting = this.sorting.bind(this);
  }
  sorting(e) {
    this.setState({ selectValue: e.target.value}, function(){
        // see how the state has changed
        // running inside setState's callback,
        // otherwise you don't get the real state
        // due to the normal (expected) delay
        console.log(this.state.selectValue)
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Sort">
          Sort by
          <select value={this.state.selectValue}onChange={this.sorting}>
            <option value="index">Pokedex Index</option>
            <option value="ascending">Ascending</option>
            <option value="descending">Descending</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```